# jQuery UI (Sortable) - Disable Sorting / Drag n Drop functionality for one box out of multiple

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI sortable plugin with `connectWith` option...

How can I restrict the Drag n Drop for one perticular box out of many boxes?

For Eg: A box with Disabled background (`.nodrop`)...

> **[Online Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/gjswortL/1/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/deadmask92/bnpzaobL/2/

I added:

```
.destination2 ul

$(".nodrop ul").sortable( "option", "disabled" );
```

Comment: **@L.A.** working as expected.. Thanks... I am **Accepting** and **Upvoting** your answer... Keep up the good work